# Android SDK path is not changed

Tags: android, android-studio-3.1

I removed the Android Studio and re-installed it.

But the SDK manager has a problem.

So I removed all of files/directories related with the Android, and re-installed.

But it is same.

I attached the screen shot.

I tried to set SDK manager path, but it was not changed...

What should I do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From android pane **Migrate to** --> *Gradle scripts* --> *local.properties* --> and then add the correct `dir`

```
  sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\xx\\xx\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```